# Switching tabs while search is focused breaks the header

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, user-interface

The new enlarge-search-on-focus functionality occasionally breaks as thus when changing tabs.

[image: breakage]

Steps for repro:

- Focus tab
- Switch to another tab
- Switch back

Reproduced in Chrome & FF 5, norepro in Safari, but the issue does seem somewhat sporadic - sometimes the header will hide like it should when refocusing the window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with Chrome 13 or FF8.

Comment: Firefox *8*? That's ridiculous. What happened to versions 6 and 7? It would be nice if that team would go back to making a *stable* browser, rather than ticking up the version number. I can't repro this on Chrome either. When you re-focus the tab, the search box re-adjusts itself after a brief moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial work-around will be pushed tonight.  It's not pretty, since [most browsers](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/842411) will fire element focus loss events when the window/tab loses focus.